# How to disable Apport pop-up message without disabling Apport?

Tags: error-handling, apport

Is there a way to disable the Apport pop-up dialog error message that appears when an Ubuntu error occurs **without** disabling Apport?

Message that appears in the pop-up: "Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error."

Comment: disable temporarily by clearing the crash directory. sudo rm /var/crash/*

Answer (score 1):

Apport doesn't actually pop up these messages, `update-notifier`does that for you.

If you want to to disable these, you can do it via

```
gsettings set com.ubuntu.update-notifier show-apport-crashes false
```

Apport will not be affected by this.

Comment: I don't know who downvotes this, the [Offical Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport#Frontend_invocation) has the same way to disable pop-ups for Apport.